# Why does the morning congregrational prayer has a higher reward then Umrah and Hajj?

Tags: hajj, umrah

Anas bin Malik, may Allah be pleased with him, who said:

> The Messenger of Allah, sallallahu `alayhi wa sallam, said:  ‘Whoever prays the morning prayer in congregation then sits remembering Allah until the sun rises, then prays two units of prayer has the reward like that of Hajj and `Umrah.’

He also said:

> Allah’s Messenger, sallallahu `alayhi wa sallam, said: ‘Complete, complete, complete (i.e. reward)’” [at-Tirmidhi, classed as Saheeh by al-Albani}

We know that performing Hajj and Umrah requires a lot of hardship and sacrifices.

1. It is difficult to comprehend fully why this small act mentioned in the above hadith would get not only the same reward but as stressed, *‘Complete, complete, complete’*. Would it not make the whole acts of hajj and umrah relatively less important and outstanding since the reward could easily be obtained everyday?
2. For a person who has already performed hajj and umrah, is there much point to make a second one since the reward could easily be obtained everyday?

Comment: Welcome to [islam.se]. Please go through the editing I have done to your question. Anytime you quote something you have to put it in blockquotes i.e. by selecting the quoted text and pressing Ctrl+q. Also visit the [about], the [help] and [meta]. And take some time to go through the [formatting](http://islam.stackexchange.com/editing-help) help, using which will improve the presentation and readability of your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that God rewards what He loves howsoever He pleases.

He has [not placed upon us in the religion any difficulty](http://quran.com/22/78), so why would you think that there's higher reward in more difficult actions?  He loves those who purify themselves, He loves those who fear Him, He loves those who are steadfast, He loves those who rely upon Him, so why should he not reward with a great reward those who not only pray *fajr* — one of the [most difficult prayers for the hypocrites](http://www.sunnah.com/malik/8/5) — but go beyond even that while remembering Him?

And if your only reason to perform hajj or umrah is for such-and-such a reward then yes, there's not much point in doing so.  But if your intention for umrah is to do what God loves because you love pleasing God, or to strengthen your own *imaan*, or to help you remember Him greatly, then of course it is worth it.  And if your *imaan* is stronger in your own community, if you can remember Him greatly in the mornings without travelling, if you can please God by staying at home, then *staying home* is worth it.

Because ultimately, it should never be about which action gains more reward — as if Heaven is some sort of midway attraction that you get to ride if you have enough points — it's about you wanting to please God because you love Him.  And having faith that He in his grace and wisdom will reward you for *whatever* good you do.

Comment: alhamdulillah.. (=
jazakallah khoiran for the answer..
how about my second question?